# i have 2 tables 1.table emp 2. emp purchase now. i want which emp purchase products along with sum and emp name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I'm using this query

```
SELECT e.Emp_name,
       COUNT(*) AS employee_count,
       SUM(s.sales_amount) AS sales_amount
FROM   sales_emp e
       INNER JOIN sales_sum1 s ON e.empid = s.empid
GROUP BY e.Emp_name
ORDER BY sales_amount DESC LIMIT 3;
```

I get back the top 3 rows of data, but I'm unable see the 1st table emp name

Comment: You have two tables: sales_emp and sales_sum1.  You're seeing sales_emp.Emp_Name, correct?  You're not selecting any other table's employee name in your query, are you?  So what exactly is the problem???

Comment: Your code is not Oracle code.  Either you get a syntax error or you are using a different database.  Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RANK` here to find the top 3 by sales:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.Emp_name, COUNT(*) AS employee_count, SUM(s.sales_amount) AS sales_amount,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(s.sales_amount) DESC) rnk
    FROM sales_emp e
    INNER JOIN sales_sum1 s ON e.empid = s.empid
    GROUP BY e.Emp_name
)

SELECT Emp_name, employee_count, sales_amount
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

Oracle does not support `LIMIT` (which is used by MySQL, SQLite, Postgres, and a few others).  Some versions of Oracle support `FETCH FIRST` syntax.

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 11 unexpected 'RANK'. syntax error line 3 at position 16 unexpected ')'. syntax error line 3 at position 18 unexpected 'OVER'.

Comment: im getting error

Comment: @BABU Sorry, missing a comma, please try it again.

Comment: can u please tell me where can i use comma

Comment: what ever you told is right but in 2 tables product name also i want can you please tell

Comment: @BABU Perhaps you just need to add the product name to the select list of the CTE.

Comment: WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.Emp_name,s.Product_Name, COUNT(*) AS employee_count, SUM(s.sales_amount) AS sales_amount,
           RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(s.sales_amount) DESC)rnk
    FROM sales_emp e
    INNER JOIN sales_sum1 s ON e.empid = s.empid
    GROUP BY e.Emp_name,s.Product_Name
  )
SELECT Emp_name,Product_Name, employee_count, sales_amount
FROM cte 
WHERE rnk <= 15;

Comment: EMP_NAME   PRODUCT_NAME  EMPLOYEE_COUNT  SALES_AMOUNT
BABU               Car                              1                          150
BABU                Bike             1                 100
BAJA  Bus                     1                  250
BAJA  Bike_TVS               1           200
Durga      Honda               1                 650
Raji        App                     1                 150
Sandhya  BMW               1                  450
Sandhya  Audi                      1                 100

Comment: result. but in emp name 2times showing .i want emp in single name with product name, sales amount. emp purchase 2 items emp name ,product name total amount. for example the above table have emp name babu. with babu name along with product details and total sum  i want